# Hubcap question

Tags: wheels, yaris

There was a huge pot-hole near my house and a number of hubcaps had accumulated nearby for obvious reasons.

What is the mathematical chance one of those hubcaps might match a missing hubcap on my Toyota Yaris?  Is it related to wheel / rim size, or the number of attach points?

Comment: Easiest way is to just check? If you are missing a hubcap and it suddenly disappeared after hitting said pothole, I'd say your chances are pretty high, like in the 80-90% range, but that's a SWAG. Really, if you want the mathematical probability of it, you should ask this question over on Math.SE. We try not to bend our minds around such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should honestly post this on a statistics forum, try Cross Validated. The hubcap is dependent on both the rim size AND the position and number of the lug nuts.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that's what I was wondering -- if the number of lug nuts was relevant, or if I could just swap it out with a similar (also round, also fake metallic color) one.

Comment: Something you could try, and I have seen it done is use zip ties. But it looks really bad.
http://imgur.com/vkviE5q